# extract single file from huge tgz file

Tags: linux, tar

I have a huge tar file (about 500G) and I wan't to extract just a single file from it.
However, when I run `tar -xvf file.tgz path/to/file` it seems like it is still loading the whole contents into memory, and takes over an hour to extract.
I've also tried to use `--exclude=ignore.txt` where ignore.txt is list of patterns in an attempt to stop it from traversing futile paths, but that doesn't seem to work.

Perhaps I don't understand tar... Is there a way to quickly extract the file?

Comment: I am wondering about the same. The file I am looking for is found quickly and extracted - and then I need to wait for an hour for the rest of the achieve to be processed :o(

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Unfortunately, in order to unpack single member of `.tar.gz` archive you have to process whole archive, and not much you can do to fix it.

This is where `.zip` (and some other formats like `.rar`) archives work much better, because `zip` format has central directory of all files contained in it with direct offsets pointing to the middle of the `zip` file, so archive members can be quickly extracted without processing whole thing.

You might ask why processing `.tar.gz` is so slow?

`.tar.gz` (often shortened as `.tgz`) is simply `.tar` archive compressed with `gzip` compressor. `gzip` is streaming compressor that can only work with one file. If you want to get any part of `gzip` stream, you have to uncompress it as a whole, and this is what really kills it for `.tar.gz` (and for `.tar.bz2`, `.tar.xz` and other similar formats based on `.tar`).

`.tar` format is actually very, very simple. It is simply stream of 512-byte file or directory headers (name, size, etc), each followed by file or directory contents (padded to 512 block size with 0 bytes if necessary). When you observe totally null 512 block for a header, this means end of `.tar` archive.

Some people think that even `.tar` archive members cannot be accessed quickly, but this is not *quite* true. If `.tar` archive contains few big files, you actually can quickly seek into next header, and thus you can find necessary archive member in few seeks (but still could require as many seeks as there are archive members). If your `.tar` archive contains of lots of tiny files, this means quick member retrieval becomes effectively impossible even for uncompressed `.tar`.

Comment: gzip can stream uncompressed data, it doesn't have to undo the whole thing.  But, since .tar is short for tape archive, you do need to traverse the whole file until you find the file you are looking for.  Although tar will keep looking because there might be another, later copy later on in the tar file.

Comment: It's not because tar is short for tape archive, but given that tar was originally designed to back up data on tape where there is no random access, having some kind of directory at the head of the file isn't really possible. As @phogg states in another answer, you can specify that you only want a single occurrence of the file.

Answer (score 11):

If you're extracting just one file from a large tar file, you're using GNU `tar`, *and you can guarantee that the tar file has never been appended to* then you can get a significant performance boost by using `--occurrence`.

This option tells tar to stop as soon as it finds the first occurrence of each file you've requested, so e.g.

```
tar xf large-backup.tar --occurrence etc/passwd etc/shadow
```

will not spool through the whole tarball after it finds one copy of each of `passwd` and `shadow`, instead it will stop. If those files appear near the end the performance gain won't be much, but if they appear even half way through a 500G file you'll save a lot of time.

For people using `tar` for single shot backups and not using real tape drives this situation is probably the typical case.

Note that you can also pass `--occurrence=NUMBER` to retrieve the NUMBERth occurrence of each file, which helps if you know that there *are* multiple versions in the archive. By default the behavior is equal to a `NUMBER` of 1.

Comment: Is there a way to create the tar so that a specific file would be first to come out? so that `--occurrence` would kick in immediately on the first file? I'm guessing it's about filenames, so something called aaaaa.jpg would come out first for example?

Comment: @Jeff: Not really. This merely prevents `tar` from continuing to search the tarball for newer versions of a file it has found. Instead it returns, as the man page says, `the Nth occurrence`. If you specify *one* file to extract on the command line *and* you say `--occurrence` then tar will exit as soon as it has found that file, and thus *effectively* stop at the "first file."

Comment: I will note in answer to the above question that tar will add files in the order specified (on the command line, if you list each file, or in your file list, if you say -T). If you let `tar` recursively scan a directory itself the files will be in directory order, which is not very predictable.

Answer (score 3):

When dealing with a large tarball use:

> `--fast-read` to extract only the first archive entry that matches filename operand, `path/to/file` in this case - which is always unique in tarball anyway

```
tar -xvf file.tgz --fast-read path/to/file
```

the above will search until it finds a match and then exit

Comment: I wanted to understand why this is still at 0 points. `man tar` (GNU tar 1.29) doesn't even print this option. However Ubuntu seems to have it [enabled by default](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/bsdtar.1.html). Reading quickly, I'm not sure what `--fast-read` does differently from `--occurrence`. But then `--occurrence` is not even on the Ubuntu page, but it is in `man tar`. Are `--fast-read` and `--occurrence` the same thing possibly?

Comment: Neither of these options are specified by the standard and, as always with non-standard options, care must be taken to be sure the utility on your system supports them. The --occurrences option is supported by GNU tar. The --fast-read option is supported by recent versions of the FreeBSD tar, packaged as bsdtar by Ubuntu. See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101561/what-are-the-differences-between-bsdtar-and-gnu-tar) for more.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the tar file format contains no centralized table of contents - so the archive must be read sequentially to locate a particular file. It was originally designed for tape backups ("tar" comes from **t**ape **ar**chive), which wouldn't have supported such an operation in any case.

So, you'll probably just have to wait.