# How to extract single file from large tar/tar.gz file

Tags: linux, tar, gzip

What I want to do is to extract a single file from a huge tar file, instead of extracting the whole tar.

I am using RHEL 6.4

I Googled it and tried the following:

```
tar --extract --file=some.tar ./env
tar: ./env: Not found in archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
tar -xf some.tar ./env
tar: ./env: Not found in archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

And yes `env` file does exist in the tar file.

I read the answer given here:
[extract single file from huge tgz file](https://superuser.com/questions/655739/extract-single-file-from-huge-tgz-file)

Is there any way I can do this single file extraction or not?

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `-t` flag to see how the filename is stored, then specify the same name at the end of your extraction tar command, including any path/directories. As in

```
tar --extract --file=some.tar exactfilename
```